# Copying files using gulpjs

Tags: gulp

I want to copy some files using the gulpjs but failing to do so.

I have created following task:

```
const {src, dest}  = require('gulp');

function copyFiles(cb) {
  return src('assets/js/*.js')
    pipe(dest('build'));
}

exports.default = copyFiles;
```

Note: paths which i have mentioned in the src and dest functions are relative to my gulpfile.js file.

Comment: I bet there's a semicolon inserted at the end of the return statement (line). What is your question, and what is expected and what is actually it doing?

Comment: Thanks @Caramiriel I missed chaining src with pipe function by ommiting dot b/w them. Thanks a lot.